# The type name 'Create' doesn't exist in the type XmlWriter

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2017, xmlwriter

I'm trying to write an Xml program on Visual Studio 2017 and have error on:

```
using System.Xml;
...
XmlWriter.Create("C:\\myxmlfile.xml", settings);
```

With this message: `The type name 'Create' doesn't exist in the type XmlWriter.`

I suspect that incomplete installation (which unfortunately didn't fixed yet) of my Visual Studio caused this problem. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that your code actually looks something like this:

```
var writer = new XmlWriter.Create("C:\\myxmlfile.xml", settings);
```

if it is then remove the `new` and it will work.
The reason is that in the XmlWriter class Create is static so can not be newed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was due a conflict with another library.
I had to specify it like :

```
System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sww)
```

Hope it work for you too.